# Why `VkPipelineStageFlagBits` does not only define pipeline stages?

Tags: vulkan

[`VkPipelineStageFlagBits`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPipelineStageFlagBits.html) defines flags corresponding to stages that we would expect in a Graphics Pipeline such as `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT` or `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT`, etc. We also have Compute Pipeline stages such as `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT`.

But there are also some flags defined here that does not seem to correspond to any Graphics or Compute Pipeline stage at all, such as `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT`, `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` and `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` (from which `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT` and `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` are defined). Instead, these are defined in the specification by referring to commands. For instance:

> `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` specifies the following commands:
>
> - All copy commands, including `vkCmdCopyQueryPoolResults`
> - `vkCmdBlitImage2` and `vkCmdBlitImage`
> - `vkCmdResolveImage2` and `vkCmdResolveImage`
> - All clear commands, with the exception of `vkCmdClearAttachments`

So if it is not a pipeline stage, why is it listed in `Vk**PipelineStage**FlagBits`? Why is it named this way? What does it mean if I use `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` as `srcStageMask` or `dstStageMask` in [`VkSubpassDependency`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkSubpassDependency.html) for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` is from transfer pipeline, which has one stage.

`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` pseudostage communicates there will be *memory domain* transfers between host and device.

`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` is a shortcut for `|`ing together all the bits applicable in a given context.

`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT` and `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` are pipeline terminators. They do not mean any stage, but they are necessary on the API level to express "before first stage", and "after last stage".

> What does it mean if I use `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` as srcStageMask or `dstStageMask` in `VkSubpassDependency` for instance?

You [are not allowed to](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkRenderPassCreateInfo-pDependencies-00837), unless that dependency is `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`.

In ordinary pipeline barrier or `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` dependency it means either some work is dependent on a copy being finished, or some copy depending on some writes to be made first.

---

How host memory sync works is that Vulkan divides it into [domains](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#memory-model-vulkan-availability-visibility). There's *host memory domain*, and there's *device memory domain*. If changes to a memory are not transitioned from one domain to the other before reading, it might be so the writes will not be visible on the other domain.

That's where `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` (plus related access mask) comes in. It instructs the driver to do this potentialy expensive and disruptive domain transfer.

Now there's a rare implicit Vulkan behavior. The [host write ordering guarantee](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-submission-host-writes). If you write from host to memory, and **then** `vkQueueSubmit` something, you don't need to do anything. Operations in that submission automatically see the host writes, and you won't use `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT`.

This doesn't work other way around though. If you want to read something on host that was written on device, you always need to use `dstStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` (followed by a fence or such), otherwisely the writes might not be visible on the host domain when you try to read them.

Third option is when you submit first, and **then** you write something on the host. Previously this could happen with Events (but that was subsequently banned), and now it can happen when using extended semaphores. In that case you need to use `srcStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` in addition to that host-device semaphore, otherwise your host writes might not be visible to the reads on that device.

Comment: Thank, the existence of a transfer pipeline explains the `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` indeed. But I'm still confused about the synchronization with `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT`. Since it is not invoked by any recorded command, then how does it knows which reads/writes needs to be waited for?

Comment: @Jingbee Commands do not "invoke" stages. You are mistaking a concept of a finite state machine with a concept of a pipeline.

Comment: I think I understand the concept of a pipeline (and if I do not, why do you think so?). The thing is, `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` does not seem to be a pipeline stage, or if it is, I don't understand the synchronization around it. Using the term "invoke" I was directly quoting from the Vulkan specification (7.1.2): "This stage is not invoked by any commands recorded in a command buffer".

Comment: @Jingbee It is a pseudo-stage. No difference on the abstract level, really. Action commands go through Graphics, Compute, and whathaveyou pipelines. Host writes\reads go through the host pseudo-pipeline, which exist next to all the other pipelines. The spec language is unfortunate then as it leads to what I have found is a common misunderstanding of what a pipeline is in computer science. Not sure you would e.g. say "ADD instruction invokes a fetch stage in the CPU" or such. The relationship is more other way around. Commands go through pipeline, **not** that pipeline is executed by commands.

Comment: @Jingbee The host sync system is not particularly complicated, so I could just append how it works to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Transfers can be inserted pretty much anywhere into a pipeline to move data between buffers. These are normal commands with dependencies that can be queued, and typically have dedicated hardware so other shaders can run in parallel. The "clear" commands use a constant value as the source for the copy operation, but still use the DMA engine, so they are in the same group.

These bits largely correspond to the resources that will be used. In the case of VkSubpassDependency, they define which resources need to be synchronized for the pipeline to deliver correct results, so if you use a Copy or Clear operation in the first subpass, you need to specify `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` in the `srcStageMask` to denote that the first subpass will use the DMA engine, so handover to the second subpass requires the write caches of the DMA engine to be flushed. Omitting this bit would allow an invalid optimization, so it is diallowed to use a Copy or Clear command then.

The "All Commands", "Top of Pipe" and "Bottom of Pipe" are just shorthands to save on negotiation during pipeline setup.